# htaccess multiple domains redirect to https://www and to specific document root

Tags: .htaccess, multiple-domains

I have 3 **LIVE** domains that point to the same document root where CMS handles each domain with it's own content.

I now need to redirect all 3 domains to HTTPS with WWW and have the the option to change each domains document root in the future.

Example what needs to happen:

http://domain1.com => https://www.domain1.com

http://www.domain1.com => https://www.domain1.com

Same must also happen for domain2.com and domain3.com

Document root for all three domain is /cms-1.1/

In the future there might be a change for domain1.com to a new document root /cms-2.1/ but for the rest of domains the document root will stay the same /cms-1.1/

Can I write one rule or multiple rules... for each domain separately or combined??

So far I came up to here:

- for document root: (for each domain)

  ```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$ [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms-1.1/*$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cms-1.1/$1 [L]
  ```
- for non-www to www: (for each domain)

  ```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
  ```
- for HTTPS: (for each domain)

  ```
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain1.com/$1 [L,R=301]
  ```

But will this work ??? Since all three domains are live, I need not to have any downtime...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this generic code (not tested)

```
# https mechanism
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#none www to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

#Document root each domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms-1.1/*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cms-1.1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hmm. It kinda works for the alias domains "domain2.com" and "domain3.com" but not for the hosting domain which is "domain1.com"... I'll check with the hosting provider if they have any idea why.

Comment: Scratch that... there was some settings on Cloudflare set wrong. All good. Solution works.